# Passing argument to a factory for a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this HTML:

```
  <div class='container-fluid' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
    <p></p>
    <b>Selected User</b>
    Enter a name: <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="user as (user.first + ' ' + user.last) for user in users | filter:$viewValue" />
</div>
```

this controller:

```
app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', ['$scope', 'getUser',function($scope, getUser) { 

  $scope.selected = "";
  getUser.success(function(data) { 
      $scope.users = data; 
  });

}]);
```

and this service:

```
app.factory('getUser', ['$http', function($http) { 

  return $http.get('https://myUrl?param=Foo') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
```

How can I pass an argument to the service to make the value of `param` in URL dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `factory` creates an object and returns it as the publically available operations.  So, you can create and return an object that wraps the HTTP call:

```
app.factory('getUser', ['$http', function($http) { 

    function myInternal(arg1) {
        return $http.get('https://myUrl?param=' + arg1) 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            });
    }
    return {
        makeMyCall: function(arg1) {
            return myInternal(arg1);
        }
    };

}]);
```

Then from the controller you can invoke the `getUser.makeMyCall` function passing in the argument.

BTW, if you are not adding anything to the promise chain that there is no need to handle the `success` and `error` function in the factory:

```
    function myInternal(arg1) {
        return $http.get('https://myUrl?param=' + arg1);
    }
    return {
        makeMyCall: function(arg1) {
            return myInternal(arg1);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way with minimal change is to change your factory so that it returns a function

```
app.factory('getUser', ['$http', function($http) { 

    var httpReq = function(param){
        return $http.get('https://myUrl?' + param + '=Foo') 
            .success(function(data) { 
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
              return err; 
            }); 
    }

    return httpReq; 
}]);
```

Now you can pass a value into your factory

```
app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', ['$scope', 'getUser',function($scope, getUser) { 

  $scope.selected = "";
  getUser('paramValue').success(function(data) { 
      $scope.users = data; 
  });

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
app.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', ['$scope', 'getUser',function($scope, getUser) { 

  $scope.selected = "";
  getUser('Foo').success(function(data) { 
      $scope.users = data; 
  });

}]);


app.factory('getUser', ['$http', function($http) { 

  return function(myParam) {
      return $http.get('https://myUrl', {param:{param:myParam}});      
  };
}]);
```